# NodeJs : Access a variable of the controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, controller

I'm a newbie in web development. I would like to know how can i access a varible in the controller in a script of html page? 
The variable is a converted xml file to json and I would like to process it with the script of the html page.

Please help me if you have any suggestions!!!!!!
Thank you

Here is my code :

```
   <div class="graph" ng-app="httpApp" ng-controller="httpController">

  {{result_fantastic_story.story.step}}

    <script>
  _.each({result_fantastic_story.story.step , function(step){
...
}
</script>
</div>
```

result_fantastic_story is a json array. {{result_fantastic_story.story.step}} displays array correctly on the page so it's the good syntax. But the probleme is that I can't declare it within the script : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .)

Comment: Save the `scope` variable under the context of `window` which could be access as `global-variable`

Comment: Is there any chance you can convert the script to a service? Having the Controller Export a value like that would seem a bit hacky to me...

Comment: @Rayon I don't understand, how?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly the script is doing? Are you trying to put something on a DOM, make an API call, or something else? @Rayon's Suggestion might be going to work, but it certainly doesnt seem like it would be the right way to go here in any case.

Comment: The script is just calling it in a variable 
var steps = result.story.step; where result is a the result of the conversion of an xml to a json inside the controller

Comment: @Takichii I think now I get what you are trying to say - you want to set the variable in NodeJS and Access it from the js in the client?

Comment: Why not do the work in your angular Controller? I cannot imagine a reason to put a script tag in the middle of the DOM. I´ll make something more precise once I am home.

Comment: Something like this: [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/7CLVsdkBlFHDv76yT0Bh?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the response! I did it but it failed : ReferenceError: steps is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1, is this normal?

Comment: It does work outside the script tough, but I need to work with it inside the script<

Answer (score 0):

HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS </title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```